# Should somebody remove the "edit to add" part of somebody else's question?

Tags: discussion, editing

Background info:

I wrote [a question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/163587/what-was-the-first-story-to-feature-a-person-alone-on-a-planet) about "first story to mention only person on planet".

One person asked if I wanted stories about a person marooned on a moon or asteroid.

Another asked if I wanted religious creation myths.

And somebody posted an answer, now deleted, that mentioned religious creation myths.

Seeing all that, I added this line to the original post.

> Edit to add: I would also consider a story about somebody stranded on an asteroid, moon, or dwarf planet. I'm not looking for religious texts or creation myths.

Then somebody removed the *Edit to add:* part from my own editing.

Now the comments with clarifying questions look inappropriate, as if the persons asking clarifying questions didn't read the text.

Was it appropriate for somebody to remove the *Edit to add:* part?

Answer (score 14):

Consensus on main meta is that "EDIT" or similar words in the body of an edited post

> are rarely needed, nor helpful.
>
> <sub>[accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127655/299342) to ["When is “EDIT”/“UPDATE” appropriate in a post?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127639/299342)</sub>

The link to the edit history at the bottom of the post will show users what edits were made to the post if anyone cares to look.

If you feel that comment(s) are made obsolete by editing please flag them. However, I left the [comment asking about religious texts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/163587/what-was-the-first-story-to-feature-a-person-alone-on-a-planet#comment434334_163587) because it contains an important link to our policy on citing religious works in answers.

Comment: Hmmm.... Yeah, I see the consensus is to **not** include "edit to add" in any updates. Except when an edit invalidates existing answers. My edit invalidated an existing answer along with a few clarifying questions left as comments, so a person could argue it either way. Right now, I prefer to leave "edit to add" within my post. Anyhow, thanks for the link to the consensus on that.

Comment: @RichS The obsolete comments are not a concern. They did their job by getting you to clarify. Normally, an edit which invalidated an existing answer would need to be rolled back. However, in this case the invalidated answer violated our policy on religious texts and needed to be deleted anyway.